# Match proceeding word without look ahead in Go

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to retrieve the table from a query string (eg. '`select foo from bar limit 10`' should return '`bar`').

I believe '`(?<=\bfrom\\s)(\\w+)`' is what I was looking for but it is unsupported by Go regexp package. (http://play.golang.org/p/MJ3DUk6uuC)

Comment: Advanced regex features are cool and all, but you rarely need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still can detect '`from xxx`', without looking the lookahead syntax [not supported](https://code.google.com/p/re2/issues/detail?id=79) by **[re2](https://code.google.com/p/re2/)**.
Since you would then capture '`from` ', you need to remove it from the result.

See [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/zvRE2u7Uok):

```
r := regexp.MustCompile("(?:\\bfrom\\s)(\\w+)")
res := r.FindAllString(strings.ToLower("select foo from bar limit 10"), 1)
if len(res) != 1 {
    panic("unable")
}
i := strings.LastIndex(res[0], " ")
fmt.Println(res[0][i+1:], i)
```

Output:

```
bar 4
```